# Windows Server 2016 File Server GPT (4K cluster size) to GPT (8K cluster size) (or Robocopy)

Tags: robocopy

We are replacing our GPT partitioned E:\ drive which is out of space, and migrating those files over to the new F:\ drive which is GPT.

The directory tree will stay the same.

E:\ drive 15TB (4K cluster size)

F:\ drive 25TB (8K cluster size)

What would be the best way to retain permissions and have minimal user impact? Robocopy? Xcopy? Restore ? 3rd tool sync tool ? I’m open to all ideas/suggestions.

my robocopy command:

```
ROBOCOPY "source" "destination" /xf "pagefile.sys" "thumbs.db" "*.tmp" /xd "DfsrPrivate" "recycler" "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /MIR /copy:DAT /ZB /MT:16 /R:1 /W:1 /NP /TEE /LOG:"C:\tmp\LogName.log"
```

my workflow:

Run RoboCopy 2 days prior to the cutover

On cutover date,export the registry key that contains all the share information.

Console into the VM, kill the nic, then run RoboCopy once more. Switch the drive letters. Reimport reg key

Comment: I do not think it matters from the cluster size - all the tools you mention are based on the file system, NOT on the blocks the files take.